# bash: if instruction that checks the number of lines from a variable fails

Tags: bash, unix

I have the following instruction:

```
if [[ ! `wc -l <<< $SILENT_LOG` -eq 1 -o ! `wc -l <<< $ACTIVE_LOG` -eq 1 ]] then
        echo "There should be only a silent report log file!" >> $DEST_DIR/$RESULT_FILE
        OK=0;
fi
```

OK should be set to 0 when SILENT_LOG or ACTIVE_LOG have 0 or more lines. The problem is that the following error is raised:

```
**./reportComparator.sh: line 26: syntax error near `-o'
./reportComparator.sh: line 26: `if [[ ! `wc -l <<< $SILENT_LOG` -eq 1 -o ! `wc -l <<< $ACTIVE_LOG` -eq 1 ]] then'**
```

Also, I tried to replace  `wc -l <<< $SILENT_LOG` with echo $SILENT_LOG | wc-l but it still does not work.

Answer (score 3):

First, the following syntax will not work:

```
$ [[ 1 -eq 1 -o 2 -eq 2 ]]
bash: syntax error in conditional expression
bash: syntax error near `-o'
```

In bash, you have two choices:

```
$ [[ 1 -eq 1 || 2 -eq 2 ]]
$ [ 1 -eq 1 -o 2 -eq 2 ]
```

For compatibility with plain POSIX shells, neither of the above should be used, the former because plain POSIX does not support `[[` and the latter because plain POSIX shells cannot parse such long tests reliably.  Instead use:

```
$ [ 1 -eq 1 ] || [ 2 -eq 2 ]
```

For the second issue, let's create a variable with three lines:

```
$ silent_log='one
> two
> three'
```

Now observe:

```
$ wc -l <<<$silent_log
1
$ wc -l <<<"$silent_log"
3
```

If you want the lines counted correctly, you need to double-quote your variables.

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax issues in your code.

For `[[...]` you can use:

```
if [[ $(wc -l < "$SILENT_LOG") -eq 1 || $(wc -l < "$ACTIVE_LOG") -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "There should be only a silent report log file!" >> $DEST_DIR/$RESULT_FILE
    OK=0
fi
```